# ¿Porque ahora obtengo este error en el logcat de Android Studio solo por poner que se compilara con java 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

Cada vez que la aplicación inicia obtengo este error. La aplicación no se cierra ni nada por el estilo, pero el Logcat de Android me arroja este error. ¿Saben como podría repararlo?.

Intente eliminar las actividades y recrearlas pero el problema persiste, no se que mas puedo hacer.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_log_in);

    mLoginBtnLogin = findViewById(R.id.login_btn_login);
    mLoginRecoverPassword = findViewById(R.id.login_recover_password);
    mLoginBtnRegister = findViewById(R.id.login_btn_register);
    mLoginField1 = findViewById(R.id.login_field_1);
    mLoginField2 = findViewById(R.id.login_field_2);
    mLoader = new KProgressHUD(this);

    mLoginRecoverPassword.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent RecoverPassword = new Intent(LogIn.this, RecoverPassword.class);
        LogIn.this.startActivity(RecoverPassword);
    });

    String mOptionsLogIn = getIntent().getStringExtra("login_info");

    if (mOptionsLogIn != null) {
        switch (mOptionsLogIn) {
            case "mail_verification_success":
                Snacky.builder()
                        .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff4e5e"))
                        .setActivity(LogIn.this)
                        .setText(getString(R.string.login_snack_message_mail_verification))
                        .setDuration(Snacky.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .error()
                        .show();

                break;
            case "user_ban":
                mUsersDB.child(mCurrentUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String mBanReason = dataSnapshot.child("reason_suspension").getValue().toString();
                        new FancyAlertDialog.Builder(LogIn.this)
                                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_notifications, Icon.Visible)
                                .setTitle(getString(R.string.wolfnginx_alert_default_title_error_funny))
                                .setMessage(getString(R.string.wolfnginx_alert_default_title_error_suspension_1) + "\n\n" +
                                        getString(R.string.wolfnginx_alert_default_title_error_suspension_2) + "\n" +
                                        mBanReason + "\n\n" +
                                        getString(R.string.wolfnginx_alert_default_message_error_3) + "\n" +
                                        getString(R.string.wolfnginx_alert_default_contact_email))
                                .setAnimation(Animation.SLIDE)
                                .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff4e5e"))
                                .setPositiveBtnBackground(Color.parseColor("#ff4e5e"))
                                .setNegativeBtnText(getString(R.string.wolfnginx_alert_default_btn_cancel))
                                .setPositiveBtnText(getString(R.string.wolfnginx_alert_default_btn_contact))
                                .isCancellable(true)
                                .OnPositiveClicked(() -> {
                                    mLoader.dismiss();
                                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                }).OnNegativeClicked(() -> {
                                    mLoader.dismiss();
                                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                }).build();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Snacky.builder()
                                .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff4e5e"))
                                .setActivity(LogIn.this)
                                .setText(getString(R.string.wolfnginx_snack_error_default_message_data_cancel) + " " + databaseError.getMessage())
                                .setDuration(Snacky.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                .setActionText(android.R.string.ok)
                                .error()
                                .show();
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
    }

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mUsersDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    mBansDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Bans");

    mLoginBtnRegister.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent Register = new Intent(LogIn.this, Register.class);
        LogIn.this.startActivity(Register);
    });

    mLoginBtnLogin.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (!mLoginField1.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !mLoginField2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            mLoader.setLabel(LogIn.this.getString(R.string.wolfnginx_loading_default_title));
            mLoader.setDetailsLabel(LogIn.this.getString(R.string.wolfnginx_loading_default_message));
            mLoader.setAnimationSpeed(1);
            mLoader.setDimAmount(0.5f);
            mLoader.setCancellable(false);
            mLoader.show();
            LogIn.this.loginUserWolfNginx(mLoginField1.getText().toString(), mLoginField2.getText().toString());
        } else {
            Snacky.builder()
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff4e5e"))
                    .setActivity(LogIn.this)
                    .setText(LogIn.this.getString(R.string.wolfnginx_snack_default_message_empty_fields))
                    .setDuration(Snacky.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setActionText(android.R.string.ok)
                    .error()
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```

El error es:

```
2019-02-18 21:31:23.404 13005-13005/network.wolfnginx.okami E/TypefaceCompatApi21Impl: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: addFontWeightStyle [class java.lang.String, int, boolean]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi21Impl.<clinit>(TypefaceCompatApi21Impl.java:74)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.<clinit>(TypefaceCompat.java:49)
        at androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompat.create(TypefaceCompat.java:190)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.setTypeface(AppCompatTextView.java:576)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:217)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:103)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:93)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1267)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1317)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:470)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at network.wolfnginx.okami.main.LogIn.onCreate(LogIn.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7084)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7075)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Comment: Agrega por favor como esta definido el TextView en tu layout.

Comment: Tambien faltaria saber como has hecho que sea compatible con java 1.8, tienes en gradle     compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

Comment: El Texview es simple solo es un texto con negrita y que dice el nombre de la aplicación. Y para que sea compatible con Java 8 lo hice con el compileOptions

Comment: Puedes actualizar tus dependencias de androidx,. 
Esto es un problema de androidx. Parece que androidx.core.graphics.TypefaceCompatApi21Impl () intenta resolver estáticamente un método con la firma addFontWeightStyle (class java.lang.String, int, boolean) de algunos internos a la clase framework android.graphics.FontFamily a través de la reflexión. Y resulta que ese método no existe.